# why does my front suspension have no spring or air valve

Tags: mountain-bike

[image]I am riding a old rally mtb the fork is a xc100 , I can find no mention of these online, and it has never a spring nor a air chamber to make the suspension work. it is recently began to stop working so I wanted to tune it. however I am lost as to how it works.
any ideas would be most useful.

many thanks

ewen

Comment: Presumably rally is a misspelling of Raleigh. And the fork is made by Suntour? If its a cheap fork, chances are it has a spring and it isn't designed to be user serviceable, so taking it apart and repairing it will be somewhat of a challenge.

Comment: hi thanks I am unaware as to the make of the for. but thank you for you point. its a bit of a shame as it has gone from 100mm of travel to just 40

Comment: What about the model of the bike?

Comment: not a clue it was purchased of eBay. I estimate it to be around the 90's if that's any help

Comment: A picture? You need to give us more details.

Comment: how do I post a pic? sorry

Comment: The helmet works better if you put it on your head.

Answer (score 5):

i had one of those some years ago. you need to check for bolts in the bottom of the legs, if there are not any you must get a long 5 alen key (about 45 cm length) take out the upper caps and introduce the long key. once you take out tha bolts in both sides you will be able to disasemble the fork, then clean averyting, grease, and put everyting together again.

Comment: Hi as a sub question what type of grease would u recomend? And would something like wd-40 work

Comment: @EwenShackel I wouldn't advise WD40 anywhere near a bike. It is primarily a DE-GREASER, which means its very effective at reducing lube.